# On the Product List in Admin, how can i change the text to a drop down or checkbox for easier product enabling and disabling?

Tags: magento-1.9, php

Below is the view, i would like to make Enabled option as `Dropdown` or `checkbox`, that auto updates when changed.

[image: Example]

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mass action. Check all products that you want to update and then choose from the right top dropdown Edit option, click Submit.